# Merge two columns keep both matching and non-matching columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm super-basic with Pandas and I'm hoping there is an easy Pandas solution with merge?  Is there a way to merge two dataframes and keep both matching and non-matching rows?
DF1

[image]

DF2

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: please, avoid using images as example and provide text only, here is how you can create a table https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: when you do a merge, use `how="outer"`